# SQL upper/lower + substring not working well

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have a table with a column named "name" between other columns. I was making experiments with sql functions and I don't know why this doesn't work. When I run this code:

```
select name , upper(SUBSTRING(name,1,1)), SUBSTRING(name,1,1) from primeraTabla
```

I get a table like:

```
name     (no column name)    (no column name)
paco     P                   p
Fernando F                   F
....
```

But when I try:

```
select * from primeraTabla where upper(SUBSTRING(name,1,1)) = SUBSTRING(name,1,1)
```

the first row with name paco should be excluded, but it is not. The filter doesn't work.

So the question is, why this filter doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **`COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`** to make the search case sensitive.

**Query**

```
select * from primeraTabla 
where upper(SUBSTRING(name,1,1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = SUBSTRING(name,1,1);
```

Even you can change the collation of the any column for any table permanently by,

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE [your_table_name]
ALTER COLUMN [your_column_name] VARCHAR(100)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it use "ASCII"

```
select * from primeraTabla 
where ascii(upper(SUBSTRING(name,1,1))) = ascii(SUBSTRING(name,1,1))
```

---

**Result:**

```
name
--------------------
Fernando
```

---

[db<>fiddle Demo Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=dfb99d9b7a0036e72c3a09a0c1612b4d)

Comment: Nice and simple